# How can I make JavaFX web browser displays alert and confirm message

Tags: java, javafx, webbrowser-control

My java web browser don't display alert("message"); and confirm("message");  either, I ussually use c# web Browser component and it's works perfectly but I'm new at this.

```
public void  openPage(String url){
    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.add(jfxPanel);
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For `alert`, register an [`onAlert` handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#onAlertProperty) with the web engine. For `confirm`, register a [`confirmHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#confirmHandlerProperty--) with the web engine. See the "User interface callbacks" section of the [`WebEngine` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

Here's a quick example:

```
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewWithAlertAndConfirm extends Application {

    private WebEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        engine = webView.getEngine();

        engine.setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));
        engine.setConfirmHandler(message -> showConfirm(message));

        String content =   
                "<html>"
                + "<head>"
                + "<script language='javascript'>"
                + "function doConfirm() {"
                + "    var accepted = confirm('Are you sure?');"
                + "    if (accepted) {"
                + "       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Accepted';"
                + "    } else {"
                + "       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Declined';"
                + "    }"
                + "}"
                + "</script>"
                + "<body>"
                + "<div><button onclick='alert(\"This is an alert!\")'>Show alert</button>"
                + "<button onclick='doConfirm()'>Confirm</button>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div id='result'/>"
                + "</body>"
                + "</html>";

        engine.loadContent(content);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(webView)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        Dialog<Void> alert = new Dialog<>();
        alert.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
        alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    private boolean showConfirm(String message) {
        Dialog<ButtonType> confirm = new Dialog<>();
        confirm.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
        confirm.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        boolean result = confirm.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.YES::equals).isPresent();

        // for debugging:
        System.out.println(result);

        return result ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty  solution :)

for alert:

```
 webView.getEngine().setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(WebEvent<String> arg0) {            
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  arg0.getData(),"Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

        });
```

for confirm:

```
   webView.getEngine().setConfirmHandler(new Callback<String, Boolean>() {
   public Boolean call(String msg) {

     int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,msg, "Mensaje",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

     boolean b = (result != 0);
     return !b;
  }});
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a `JOptionPane` on the FX Application Thread. This code will hang on some systems (e.g. on a Mac).

Comment: I don't want to use Stage and I dont want my class extends aplication

Comment: So don't. You can still use the handlers in my answer, no? (Just remove the reference to the stage and don't call `initOwner`.) If you want to use a `JOptionPane` you need to thread it correctly and execute the `JOptionPane` code on the Event Dispatch thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. But the code you have posted here is broken.

Comment: can you edit your post and post the code without Stage ?and sorry I'm new at this

Comment: Sure: see update. Now the `onAlert` on `confirmHandler` do not use `Stage` at all.

Comment: there is a problem with your answer , you Dialog always return true because of this    return confirm.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.YES::equals).isPresent();

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Have you actually tried running the code I wrote? It returns `true` if you press "Yes", `false` if you press "No", and `false` if you just close the dialog. See updated answer, which logs the result.