# JavaFX Webview not showing alert box

Tags: java, javafx-2

So I started using JavaFX recently and one of it's features is WebView. It looks cool but what I discovered is that when button is clicked which invokes alert box then it is not displayed (it is invisible, but actually I know it is there).

How can I make it to be visible to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually I found an answer that was exactly the same I wanted and it has been answered earlier. Link: [How can I make JavaFX web browser displays alert and confirm message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880186/how-can-i-make-javafx-web-browser-displays-alert-and-confirm-message)

(So this question in this thread is a possible duplicate, but maybe it is good if there is more questions like this, then it is easier to find answer for such similar problem)