# Java Swing webEngine.executeScript not firing within HTML Javafx webview

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, webview

Hey all I've been at this for awhile. I cannot seem to get it correct from all the examples i have seen so far. It seems it would be easy but I'm at a lose.

My HTML:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();

webView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
webView.getEngine().loadContent(""+
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
    "<html>\r\n" + 
        "<head>\r\n" + 
        "</head>\r\n" +
        "<body>" +
                    "<div class=\"chatbox\" style=\"document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';\">\r\n" + 
                    "       <div class=\"chatlogs\">\r\n" + 
                    "           <div class=\"animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp\">" +
                    "                   <div class=\"chat friend\">\r\n" + 
                    "                   <div class=\"user-photo\"><img src=\"" + pic1 + "\"></div>\r\n" + 
                    "                   <p class=\"chat-message\">Whats up!</p>\r\n" + 
                    "                   <span class=\"timefriend\">11:01pm Oct 25 2019</span>\r\n" + 
                    "               </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           </div>" +
                    "           <div class=\"animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp\">" +
                    "               <div class=\"chat self\">\r\n" + 
                    "                   <div class=\"user-photo\"><img src=\"" + pic2 + "\"></div>" + 
                    "                   <p class=\"chat-message\">Not much yo!</p>\r\n" + 
                    "                   <span class=\"timeself\">11:01 PM | Oct 11 2019</span>\r\n" + 
                    "               </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           <div class=\"animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp\">" +
                    "               <div class=\"chat friend\">\r\n" + 
                    "                   <div class=\"user-photo\"><img src=\"" + pic1 + "\"></div>" + 
                    "                   <p class=\"chat-message\">Whats up!</p>\r\n" + 
                    "                   <span class=\"timefriend\">11:01 PM | Oct 11 2019</span>\r\n" + 
                    "               </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           <div class=\"animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp\">" +
                    "               <div class=\"chat friend\">\r\n" + 
                    "                   <div class=\"user-photo\"><img src=\"" + pic1 + "\"></div>" + 
                    "                   <p class=\"chat-message\">Whats up!</p>\r\n" + 
                    "                   <span class=\"timefriend\">11:01 PM | Oct 11 2019</span>\r\n" + 
                    "               </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           </div>\r\n" + 
                    "           <div id=\"nextChatHolder\"></div>" +
                    "       </div>\r\n" + 
                    "   </div>\r\n" +
                    "   <div class=\"footer\"></div>" + 
                    "   <script language=\"javascript\">\r\n" + 
                    "       function app.test() {\r\n" + 
                    "           window.scrollBy(0, 20); \r\n" + 
                    "           alert('done');\r\n" +
                    "       }\r\n" + 
                    "   </script>" +
                    "</body>\r\n" + 
                "</html>");
```

And this is the java I am using (and trying to get working):

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>()
            {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> o, State old, final State state)
                {
                    if (state == State.SUCCEEDED)
                    {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webView.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                        //webView.getEngine().executeScript("javaObj.start()");
                    }
                }
            });

private class JavaApp {
        public void test() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
```

I would think that doing:

```
function app.test() {\r\n" + 
    window.scrollBy(0, 20); \r\n" + 
    alert('done');\r\n" +
}
```

and calling it via:

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript("test()");
```

Not even this works...../

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript("alert('testing')");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Calling a Java-method from JavaScript

For calling the Java-method `JavaApp#test()` from JavaScript, the most important part of the implementation is already included in your *second* code snippet. Only the call itself is still missing, e.g.

```
<button onclick='app.test();'>Call JavaApp#test-method</button>
```

However, two important things must be taken into account: First, the nested class `JavaApp` **must** be `public`. Second, the application **must** hold a reference to the `JavaApp`-instance which is needed for the callback from JavaScript to execute the method (see [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), section `Calling back to Java from JavaScript`).

Thus you've to modify your code as follows:

```
JavaApp javaApp = new JavaApp();             // Hold a reference...
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> o, State old, final State state) {
        if (state == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject win = (JSObject) webView.getEngine().executeScript("window");
            win.setMember("app", javaApp);   // Use the reference...
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
public class JavaApp {                       // Change the access modifier from private to public...
    public void test() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

---

### Calling a JavaScript-method from Java

If you want to call a JavaScript method from Java, e.g. `test()`, this is done with

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript("test()");
```

As an example I use the `test()`-method given in your *third* snippet, where however the name **must** be changed from `app.test()` to `test()`. If `webView.getEngine().executeScript("test()");` is called, `test()` is executed *with the exception* of the `alert()`-method. This is because for some JavaScript-methods (like `window.alert()`) the `WebEngine` forwards the request to a callback (`onAlert` in the case of `window.alert()`). If the callback isn't defined, the request is ignored (see [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), section *User Interface Callbacks*). E.g., the callback for `alert()` can be defined as follows:

```
webView.getEngine().setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));
```

where `showAlert(String msg)` is a custom method and `msg` contains the original message (`done` in the case of your `test()`-method), e.g.:

```
private void showAlert(String msg){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Custom Alert");
    alert.setHeaderText("");
    alert.setContentText(msg);
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

You can find more examples in [How can I make JavaFX web browser displays alert and confirm message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880186/how-can-i-make-javafx-web-browser-displays-alert-and-confirm-message).

**EDIT:**

Example-code for the calling of a Java-method from JavaScript: When the button is pressed, the Java-method `JavaApp#test()` is called from JavaScript, which outputs the text `done` in a textarea.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class WebViewExecuteJavaFromJavaScript extends Application {

    private TextArea textArea;

    private static String HTML_STRING = "" +
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
        "<html>\r\n" + 
        "    <head>\r\n" + 
        "    </head>\r\n" +
        "    <body>" +
        "        <button onclick='app.test();'>Call Java-method JavaApp#test()...</button>" +    // Call Java-method JavaApp#test()...
        "    </body>\r\n" + 
        "</html>";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.loadContent(HTML_STRING);

        JavaApp javaApp = new JavaApp();    
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((o, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject win = (JSObject) webView.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                win.setMember("app", javaApp);                                                   // Enable call of Java-method from JavaScript...
            }
        });

        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.getChildren().addAll(webView, textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
        stage.setTitle("Demo: Execute Java from JavaScript");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(300); 
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class JavaApp {
        public void test() {
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "done ");
        }
    }
}
```

Example-code for the calling of a JavaScript-method from Java: When the button is pressed, the JavaScript-method `test()` is called from Java, which outputs the text `done` in a textarea and in a dialog.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewExecuteJavaScriptFromJava extends Application {

    private static String HTML_STRING = "" +
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
        "<html>\r\n" + 
        "    <head>\r\n" + 
        "    </head>\r\n" +
        "    <body>" +
        "        <textarea id=\"textarea\" name=\"textarea\" cols=55 rows=3 wrap=\"virtual\"></textarea>" + 
        "        <script language=\"javascript\">\r\n" + 
        "            function test() {\r\n" + 
        "                textarea.value+='done '; \r\n" + 
        "                alert('done');\r\n" +                                      // Is ignored as long as no callback is defined...
        "            }\r\n" + 
        "        </script>" +
        "    </body>\r\n" + 
        "</html>";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.loadContent(HTML_STRING);
        webEngine.setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));                  // Define callback for JavaScript-alert...

        Button button = new Button("Call JavaScript-method test()...");
        button.setOnAction(event -> webView.getEngine().executeScript("test()"));   // Call JavaScript-method test()...

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.getChildren().addAll(button, webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
        stage.setTitle("Demo: Execute JavaScript from Java");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(300); 
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void showAlert(String msg){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Custom Alert");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText(msg);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems not to call out to the javascript. I placed a button on the html page that called the same function (test()) and when i start it up it does nothing but if i click on the button then it displays the alert box from java. I need to be able to call that test() function within my app and have it fired off.

Comment: I would recommend not to use the JavaScript-`alert` for the initial testing, as it only works after the implementation of the `setOnAlert/showAlert`-stuff. Use another output, e.g. in a textarea or something like that. The `alert`-callback can be implemented later (if it is needed at all) if the JavaFX->JavaScript call itself works.
Actually, the implementation is not very complex. Maybe we are talking at cross purposes or in your environment there is an additional problem. I think the easiest way is to post my testcode, which runs without any problems on my machine.